# How to use AJW Feed Parser?

Tags: xml

I'm really stuck on how to get this working. I don't know what I need to include to get the plugin to output data.

Example XML feed:

```
<quote_feed version="1">
    <latest_price>
        <time>13:24:28</time>
        <mid_price>49.00</mid_price>
        <offer_price>50.00</offer_price>
        <bid_price>48.00</bid_price>
    </latest_price>
</quote_feed>
```

What tags to I need to output the bid price for example? Thanks for anyone's help!

Tags I'm using:

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser 
    url="feed name"
    cache_refresh="10"
    limit="8"
    debug="true"
    date="pubDate"
}

<p>{mid_price}</p>

{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

Error output:

> Cache file exists
>
> Cache file is fresh (51 seconds remaining)
>
> No tags available.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include the template tags you are currently using and what output or error you get. Also, you'll probably find Feed Parser's `debug` parameter useful ([see the docs](https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_feedparser#markdown-header-debug)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the child elements of `latest_price`, you need to set it as the root of the loop.

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser 
    url="feed name"
    cache_refresh="10"
    limit="8"
    debug="true"
    itempath="/quote_feed/latest_price"
}
    <p>{mid_price}</p>
{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```